# Create new site on WordPress multisite, https:// not applied

Tags: wordpress, ssl, multisite

So the story begin, I installed new WordPress multisite for my client with ssl applied. Then, it should have `https://`. The ssl perfectly well done, where do I know it? because all `http://` now redirect to `https://`. I don't have any issue with ssl. I use subdomain for the multisite.

Issue came when I try create new site. It's created the new site but have a non `https://`. Looks like this `http://test.thesite.com/` instead `https://test.thesite.com/`. This behaviour makes all things programmatically content (e.g. create menu) have non `https://` also. This is problem because even can redirect to `https://` it makes the redirect always working, where it doesn't need to be like that if the url already have `https://`. FYI: it's working great in local environment.

I also have searched for it but no luck, only when I asked friend, he have same problem with me. He said it's a `is_ssl()` function that I need to rewrite the original one on a theme functions. But the issue raised again, it's a super admin level not on theme level, how can I inject it on super admin level. Or maybe anyone have suggestion for me what to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So then, finally I try to investigate myself. It's a feature not a bug. The condition itself not allow user to have a https even they install wildcard ssl and forced to ssl. It will never happen the subdomain multisite install having ssl by nature, except you edit manually the url in the network site management. There is condition that only subfolder/subdirectory will have ssl. Not sure what the reason behind it. But the problem solved and time to move on. You can use plugin for this.